# CruiseControl.net duplicate NAnt timings

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I'm trying to setup CruiseControl.net webdashboard at the moment. So far it works nice, but I have a problem with the NAnt Build Timing Report.

Firstly, my current `ccnet.config` file looks something like this:

```
<project name="bla">
...
<prebuild>
 <nant .../>
</prebuild>
<tasks>
 <nant .../>
</tasks>
<publishers>
 <nant .../>
</publishers>
...
</project>
```

As the build completes, NAnt timing report displays three duplicate summaries. Is there a way to fix this without changing the project structure?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this can be solved by selecting only the first `<buildresults>` node in webdashboard's NAntTiming.xsl. Because each duplicate summary contains the same info this change in `<div id="NAntTimingReport">` section seems to be sufficient:

```
<xsl:variable name="buildresults" select="//build/buildresults[1]" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to check out Hudson. It has the benefit of being much easier to configure than CruiseControl. There's a bit about using it for NAnt [here](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/NAnt+Plugin).